# 2 XAML reference to single C# class (Universal App 8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Short story : can you make 2 XAML to reference into single C# class? If so, how do you add the reference in the XAML?

Long story : I'm currently making an Universal App for 8.1 in VS. After investigating the code-behind, both platform have same codes (identical). So my plan is to put the class for code-behind in the `Shared` folder, but I still don't know how to make both XAML (Windows 8.1 and WP8.1) to refer to this class as code-behind.

I've read this one : [How do you reference a class through xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343808/how-do-you-reference-a-class-through-xaml)
But this is for WPF, and it specified the class as `static`

edit : I'm not making the XAML into shared file, since I've designed them platform-specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the x:Class attribute of the Page element in XAML

However, it would be better to use two xaml.cs files for each xaml page in the windows store and windows phone projects, and have the common code in a separate class in the Shared Project.

Still better, you could keep all your code in the shared project, and use a single xaml page and single xaml.cs class for both phone and tablet, by using the VisualStateManager. This is what you will have to do when you port your app to Windows 10, which is a truly universal app.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just put the xaml.cs file in the shared project, or create a third file for the shared code and declare it as partial.  Then implement the differences in the projects.

However, if you do this, I think you'll have problems with adding event handlers to the xaml, much as you do if you create a base class and derive from it, as the handlers will be added to the local project, not the shared one.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what crossed my mind before, but I prefer that the XAML.cs is complete class (not abstract or partial). I've remembered somewhere that this can be done by adding the reference tag right at the top of XAML tags, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use code-behind as less as possible. XAML is designed with MVVM in mind, so code-behind should be minimal, ideally empty. Besides MVVM, there're attached behaviors, custom controls etc. which help moving code from code-behind.

If you can't get rid of code-behind completely, use your usual tactics of sharing a common piece of code — just move the code into a separate class, for example, or use class hierarchy.

Note that besides XAML and code-behind, there's a generated file which connects control names to control fields etc., so there's more code than you see. Code-behind relies on this generated code, so it can't be shared within the same project, even if the code is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas (may not be perfect):

1. Add the UI of both controls into one XAML file and then just hide/remove the unnecessary one.
2. Use a [template (custom) control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/10/15/building-a-custom-control-using-xaml-and-c.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Files in the shared project count as part of the other projects that reference the shared project. When you're building the configuration specific project it doesn't matter if a file is in that project directly or if it is in the shared project.

That means that you can leave the .xaml files in the target-specific projects and move the .xaml.cs file to the shared folder.

For Universal Windows apps in Windows 10 it's even easier: the controls will all be the same so you don't need separate code. If you do want to tailor your experience to different devices you don't need a shared project but can use device qualifiers to provide separate xaml files for different targets.

I discuss using partial classes and resource dictionaries to share code in my blog entry [Strategies for sharing code in XAML-based Universal apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/10/02/strategies-for-sharing-code-in-xaml-based-universal-apps.aspx)